# Phonegap in Android and iOS - Suggestions for building an app from scratch

Tags: android, ios, cordova, directory

this is just for personal knowledge, I will really appreciate your comments. I wanna build an Android/iOS app in phonegap, basically it's a business listing app, each business listing will have this data:

- Name
- Picture
- Address
- Phone
- Map Location [latitud,longitude] so I can use a Map API.

I want to have all the directory listings inside the app, so you can use it "offline" not the maps of course, for using the maps you must be online.

So my questions are:

- Suggestions about how saving the data, which topics do you recommend me to read
- Is there any way to buy/download maps of countries and put them on my app, so the user don't need to be online to check where is located the business listing.
- Do you think it's a good idea to develop this idea with phonegap? or do you recommend another methods/frameworks ?

I hope it's clear, sorry for my broken english! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can use [Sqlite Database](http://www.sqlite.org/quickstart.html) to store the data. Please read the document provided in the link :http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage.
2. You can use Google Maps API during offline. But during online, you can use the PhoneGapAPI provided in the link :http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#Geolocation
3. Yes, you can use phonegap as it is the bestway for your Application. For more information please go through the PhoneGap Documentation link:http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/index.html

Comment: can you tell me,is geolocation Api of phonegap work online or offline.

Comment: Hi Avadhani, thanks for the information, it was very helpful. But I have one more question how can I use the Google Maps API offline?

Comment: Yes, To implement the Offline Google Maps, you can refer this link to download the code:http://code.google.com/p/ogmaps/

Answer (score 2):

1.Save data in SharePreferences or sqllite.
2. Use google or bing maps api is more easy. It's expensive to get the local map data and update it.